Regex optimization for legacy data to json
I have a legacy data format which looks similar to Json. An example is shown in the code block below:
1  {
2    base = {
3      attributeNumericName = V1D,
4      attributeName = hello,
5      attributeFloat = 1.0,
6      attributeQuotes = "a\b",
7      canContainLists = [
8        1.0,
9        2.0
10      ],
11     canContainStackedData = [
12       {
13         stackedAttribute = 1.0
14       }
15     ]
16   }
17 }

To be able to read this in efficiently in python, I am converting the text using regex replacements. I am using the following three replacements:



Action
Source
Replacement
Affects line(s)




Replace all attributes with numeric values
([\w]{1,}) = ([\d\.]{1,},?)
"\1": \2
5, 13


Replace all attributes with string values
([\w]{1,}) = ([\w]{1,})
"\1": "\2"
3, 4


Replace all remaining attributes
([\w\d]{1,}) = 
"\1": 
2, 6, 7, 11



Because these searches have to pass through the contents three times, they are quite slow. In total I need to investigate several terabytes of files. Therefore, I am looking to optimize this. I've been trying to figure out how to combine these three replacements in one, but without any success so far. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The problem is that your close_to_json format supports nested structures, where the re module is not very good. I would instead use a custom parser here: PLY (a python implementation of Lex+Yac) should be a nice tool for that.

After looking at your sample
{
  base = {
    attributeNumericName = V1D,
    attributeName = hello,
    attributeFloat = 1.0,
    canContainLists = [
      1.0,
      2.0
    ],
    canContainStackedData = [
      {
        stackedAttribute = 1.0
      }
    ]
  }
}

it looks YAML-like for me, but using = rather than : . I did save it as file.txt and then do
import yaml  # pip install pyyaml
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    document = f.read().replace(" = ", ": ")
data = yaml.safe_load(document)
print(data['base']['attributeName'])
print(data['base']['attributeFloat'])
print(type(data['base']['attributeFloat']))

gives output
hello
1.0
<class 'float'>

Compared to your original approach this requires external dependency namely PyYAML but does not use re module at all. I am unable to say which solution will be faster based on just one case, so please before using this approach select reasonable number of examples from your data heap and measure run time against alternative solutions.
(tested in PyYAML 5.4.1)
EDIT: after learning that this solution is too slow for your use case I investigated how to ameloriate that and found fastyaml which can be used following way
import fastyaml  # pip install fastyaml
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    document = f.read().replace(" = ", ": ")
data = fastyaml.loads(document)
print(data['base']['attributeName'])
print(data['base']['attributeFloat'])
print(type(data['base']['attributeFloat']))

gives output same as above and my brief experiments showed that fastyaml is 2 orders of magnitude faster than PyYAML.
(fastyaml 0.1.0)

Thank you for the option. I tried running it and it indeed works, but for my test file it takes significantly longer. My original conversion and consequent loading in json for my example file takes 23.1s. This solution and loading in yaml takes 2m28.0s. Therefore, this solution is not suitable.

@SybrenZwetsloot I ameloriated my answer by adding faster alternative

That indeed reduced the execution time to 2.1s. I will mark this as the accepted answer unless a faster solution comes along. Thank you very much.

IMHO, this is way too complex for handling that with regexes, because a json object can be arbitrarily nested, and regular expressions are generaly not very good with nested structures.
I would use PLY here. I have rapidly written a functional demo for your json like language. It still lacks proper error handling but can successfully parse your example data as well as deeply nested structures. The only requirement is that the top level element has to be a mapping.
Here is my current demo code:
t = """{
   base = {
     attributeNumericName = V1D,
     attributeName = hello,
     attributeFloat = 1.0,
     attributeQuotes = "a\\b",
     canContainLists = [
       1.0,
       2.0
      ],
     canContainStackedData = [
       {
         stackedAttribute = 1.0
       }
     ]
   }
 }"""

from ply.lex import lex
from ply.yacc import yacc
import pprint


# Tokenizer
tokens = ('LBRACE', 'RBRACE', 'QUOTED', 'LBRACKET', 'RBRACKET', 'INT', 'FLOAT',
          'NAME', 'COMMA', 'EQUAL')

t_ignore = ' \t\r\n'        # ignored elements
t_LBRACE = r'\{'
t_RBRACE = r'\}'
t_LBRACKET = r'\['
t_RBRACKET = r'\]'
t_COMMA = ','
t_EQUAL = '='

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'(\d+\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d+)'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_INT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_QUOTED(t):
    r'"(("")|[^"])+"'
    t.value = t.value[1:-1].replace('""', '"')
    return t

t_NAME = r'\w+'

def t_error(t):
    print('OFFENDING token', t.value, file=sys.stderr)
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex()

# Parser

def p_map(p):
    '''map  : LBRACE items RBRACE
            | LBRACE items COMMA RBRACE'''
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_items_simple(p):
    'items : NAME EQUAL element'
    p[0] = { p[1]: p[3]}

def p_items(p):
    'items : items COMMA NAME EQUAL element'
    p[1][p[3]] = p[5]
    p[0] = p[1]
    
def p_list(p):
    '''list : LBRACKET elements RBRACKET
            | LBRACKET elements COMMA RBRACKET'''
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_elements_simple(p):
    'elements : element'
    p[0] = [p[1]]

def p_elements(p):
    'elements : elements COMMA element'
    p[1].append(p[3])
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_element(p):
    '''element  : INT
                | FLOAT
                | QUOTED
                | NAME
                | list
                | map'''
    p[0] = p[1]

parser = yacc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint.pprint(parser.parse(t))

It gives as expected:
{'base': {'attributeFloat': 1.0,
          'attributeName': 'hello',
          'attributeNumericName': 'V1D',
          'attributeQuotes': 'a\\b',
          'canContainLists': [1.0, 2.0],
          'canContainStackedData': [{'stackedAttribute': 1.0}]}}

This parser is even tolerant for lists or mappings having a terminal comma, and supports doubled quotes in quoted fields ('a"b' has to be written as '"a""b"')...

My reason for using json is how far the parser is optimized and the similarity of the original file to json format. With the single line provided by Salt this is significantly faster than a ply solution.

@SybrenZwetsloot: I do agree with that. I just wanted to insist that regexes are great as long as no corner cases are present. For example what would you think about {cursedattribute = "a=b"}. PLY will safely decode it but changing all the = in : will not.
